# Office365 API, private calendar appoinments

Tags: office365

I am fetching calendar events from Office365 via the REST API using Oauth/Odata. The returned [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#EventResource) does not seem to have any property telling me whether the appointment was marked 'private' by its creator. So, my question is; can I find out, and if so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you see is what you can get with the API today. It's a good suggestion to include though, I'll pass it along to our dev team.

**UPDATE:** The Event entity now has a `Sensitivity` property that should provide this information. From the metadata:

```
<EnumType Name="Sensitivity">
  <Member Name="Normal" Value="0"/>
  <Member Name="Personal" Value="1"/>
  <Member Name="Private" Value="2"/>
  <Member Name="Confidential" Value="3"/>
</EnumType>
```

Comment: This should definitely be included. Seems like Microsoft is always behind everyone else when it comes to their APIs...

Comment: Jason is there an update to this? We're running into this same problem... the lack of any visibility information in the event entity.

Comment: Yes, we added the Sensitivity property, but I see it is not on MSDN. I'll make sure the right folks know about it.